# Network Share set permissions don't work

Tags: macos, terminal, permission, sharing

I'm trying to use set default permissions for directories and files but not having much joy. What I am trying to share a specific directory on a local external drive connected to the server internally. Everyone in the group has access to the drive and can view all the files.

However once a new file is created by *mac08*, the group permissions are not set and only that user has access to modify it.

Here is an example of two txt files. The one created by *mac08* has 644 permissions and all other users like *mac07* etc. can't write to the file.

I have a group called staff and have added everyone to it, but new files created don't follow.

```
drwxrwxrwx+ 159 root  wheel  5406 22 Aug 11:08 PROJECTS
 0: group:Staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
```

New file created:

```
-rw-rw-rw-@ 1 root   wheel     351 22 Aug 23:17 test4.rtf
 0: group:Staff allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
 1: user:aserver allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
 2: user:ckadmin allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity

-rw-r--r--@ 1 mac08  wheel     352 22 Aug 23:26 testet11.rtf
 0: group:Staff allow read,write,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr
```

I can manually update the permissions through the **Get Info** window but this requires me to reset permissions every time a person saves a new file to the drive. Any idea what it could be?

Comment: Who created the file test4.rtf?

Comment: I did but then manually reset the permissions so that Group could have access.

Comment: You did this with your root user? Or has the root user ownership been propagated to subsequent files by updating the permissions in the get info window?

Comment: Yes if I use get info and reset permissions from the root folder Project it does propagate to all folders. But without that if I create new folder or file it only sets permissions for RWX for user who created it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a properly working *Projects* share do the following:

On your external disk create a folder "Projects". Share this *Projects* with default permissions in Server.app > File Sharing. The default permissions are 755, the default owner is the user who created the folder and his primary group (e.g. adminuser:admin):

```
drwxr-xr-x+   6 adminuser  admin  -       204 Aug 23 10:54 Projects
 0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

In this folder create another folder with the name *Projects*. Change the permissions to 770 and the group to staff:

```
mkdir Projects
chown adminuser:staff Projects
chmod 770 Projects
```

The permissions now look like this:

```
drwxrwx---+   6 adminuser  staff  -       204 Aug 23 10:54 Projects
 0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

Then add an ACL for the group *staff*:

```
chmod +a "group:staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit" Projects
```

with the result:

```
drwxrwx---+ 2 adminuser  staff  -   68 Aug 23 11:09 Projects
 0: group:staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 1: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
```

The complete path to the Projects folder (containing a *test* folder and a test.txt file - *Data* is the name of my volume on the external disk) is then:

```
/Volumes/Data/Projects/Projects:
total 0
drwxrwx---+ 4 adminuser  staff  - 136 Aug 23 11:24 . #this is /Volumes/Data/Projects/Projects
 0: group:staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 1: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwxr-xr-x+ 6 adminuser  admin  - 204 Aug 23 11:09 .. #this is /Volumes/Data/Projects
 0: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
drwxr-xr-x+ 2 adminuser  staff  -  68 Aug 23 11:24 test
 0: group:staff inherited allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit
 1: user:_spotlight inherited allow list,search,file_inherit,directory_inherit
-rw-r--r--+ 1 adminuser  staff  -   0 Aug 23 11:24 test.txt
 0: group:staff inherited allow read,write,execute,append,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity
 1: user:_spotlight inherited allow read,execute
```

Now any subsequent file and folder of */Volumes/Data/Projects/Projects* can be modified by any user in the group *staff*. You may tweak/tighten some of the permissions by not adding them (e.g. readextattr and writeextattr)

Comment: Great looks to be working thanks, now how come that can not be done thought UI? appreciate he help.

Comment: @namit It can be done partially with the get info window by adding a 4th entry (e.g. a new group or user). It's not as fine-grained though. Else: [propedit](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/freeware/propedit/overview/)

Comment: Thanks appreciate your help banging head off wall why this kept resetting and hit and miss on users.

Comment: @namit This is standard UNIX behavior. You may change umask though - which is not recoommended. Standard umask is 022. If you change it to 002 you will get a similar behavior as with the provided chmod +a command. The linked app (somehow abandoned-ware) works at least with 10.9.

Comment: @namit If the linked app (PropEdit works) in your system, you can [legally](http://www.eosgarden.com/en/freeware/propedit/buy/) use the following key to register it:  0GYF-CMX2-49X3-B1VH-8CA9

Comment: After 2 days of messing with this have moved all files to new disk and this seams to be working much smoother. Something looks to be definitely broken with internal disk.

Comment: @namit Hmm primary disks???

Comment: Have 2 disks in server and both seam to not take permissions correctly, have it connected to external hard disk and sharing off that. Will wait and see if users are happy.