# Others can't edit a file after creating a file and copying it to Mac Server 5.7.1

Tags: permission, osx-server, monterey

Monterey Mac Server 5.7.1, client is on macOS 12.3.1 Monterey, has been given staff read/write access by the server. Creates a file and drops it on the server, copies. Another user with the same access privilege's can't edit it. The creator has to change permissions for staff to Read & Write for that file. How do I allow clients to create files and copy to the server without this restriction?

Comment: How is the file „dropped“? SMB network share our FTP upload? Where is it uploaded to? User’s folder, public folder? What are the user access rights of the folder? Please edit your answer to include the answers to these questions.

Comment: Drag and drop onto SMB network share, public folder, staff read/write access rights. Thank you for asking.

Comment: What is the permission on the directory in which you want user to create the file ?

Answer (score 1):

All good I found the answer here, thanks for helping: [Network Share set permissions don't work](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250222/network-share-set-permissions-dont-work?rq=1)

chmod +a "group:staff allow list,add_file,search,add_subdirectory,delete_child,readattr,writeattr,readextattr,writeextattr,readsecurity,file_inherit,directory_inherit” Desktop